# Is there a word to describe an irrational demand?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

For the longest time, I have been searching for a word to describe irrational demands. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an example of such a demand, or a sentence you want to use this word in?

Comment: Without context, I don't think this question is answerable.

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests," If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities: *[pipe dream](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pipe_dream)*, "A plan, desire, or idea that will not likely work; a near impossibility";   *[whim](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whim)*, "fanciful impulse, or whimsical idea", where  *[fanciful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fanciful)* means "imaginative or fantastic; unreal or imagined" and meanings of *[whimsical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whimsical)* include "capricious; odd; peculiar;"; and  *[delusion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delusion)*, "A false belief that is resistant to confrontation with actual facts."

The first two of these (*pipe dream* and *whim*) are more like requests or wishes than they are demands; delusions, on the other hand, often have the force of demands, in that a delusional individual is likely to insist upon you, too, believing a lie.

*[Absurdities](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absurdity)* is another possibility, but like my other suggestions it represents the "irrational" aspect of requests more so than the "demand" aspect.  For the latter aspect, try
*[draconian](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draconian)*, "highly strict".  The excess associated with draconian measures (*e.g.*, [death penalty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_%28lawgiver%29) for minor offenses) lends it a sense of irrationality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a term that would work in every context.  But to add to **jwpat7**'s list, you could use [*red tape*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/red_tape) or [*bureaucracy*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bureaucracy) for when the demand has no real justification, it's just there because it's there (or because it's a relic from an outdated process).